# Node ftp get + pipe writestream very slow on some network

Tags: node.js, node-streams

I've a strange issue with a piped writestream.

The code is pretty simple, im using the module "ftp":

```
console.log("=> Before GET: "+new Date().toJSON());
ftp_client.get(file_path, function(err, stream){
    console.log("=> After GET: "+new Date().toJSON());
    
        stream.once('close', function() {
            console.log("=> Close: "+new Date().toJSON());
            console.log(" => " + path + " download success");
            return wcb(null, path);
        });

        stream.once('data', function(buffer) {
            console.log("=> Data: "+new Date().toJSON()+" => "+buffer.length);
        });
        stream.once("end", function(){
            console.log("=> End: "+new Date().toJSON());
        });
        stream.once("finish", function(){
            console.log("=> Finish: "+new Date().toJSON());
        })
    stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path));

});
```

I want to download a small file (197 B):

1. When i use filezilla with my phone as wifi access point the download
   is instant.
2. When i use this code with my phone as wifi access point
   the download is instant.
3. When i use filezilla with my box as wifi
   access point the download is instant
4. When i use this code with my
   box as wifi access point the download take more than 30s =>
   stream.once("close", fn) is called only after 30s !see output bellow

   => Before GET: 2023-04-17T09:42:34.053Z

   => After GET: 2023-04-17T09:42:34.100Z

   => Data: 2023-04-17T09:42:34.101Z => 197

   => End: 2023-04-17T09:43:07.930Z

   => Close: 2023-04-17T09:43:07.930Z

   xxx.csv download success

   => Finish: 2023-04-17T09:43:07.931Z

I have the issue only on a specific network, and only with this code as it works fine with filezilla.

box wifi speed test: 100Mb
phone wifi speed test: 8Mb

What can cause this kind a issue ?